# What URL can I submit as a sitemap for a Blogger blog to Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, google-index, xml-sitemap, blogger

In many of the articles, I found that I can submit sitemap of my blogger blog by inputting `atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500`
as my sitemap URL. But when I did this, I got a URL error saying that it couldn't fetch.

I've also tried `example.com/sitemap.xml`. None of it works. And on the old search console, it shows pending.

Now google automatically index some of my page randomly. So I need to manually input all the pages on URL inspection and check if its indexed and request for index. It takes so much time. It will be very helpful if I can do it by a sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

Google changed things in 2014.   Since then, the

> `example.com/sitemap.xml`

style of sitemap description has worked.   And now (I think due to HTTPS implementation ... am not 100% sure if this is the full reason) you need to use

> `www.example.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Don't you usually have to submit sitemaps with the `https://` on the front?

Comment: None of it works.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?    www.example.com/sitemap.xml   is working for me on one of my custom domain sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `www.domain.example` you would submit `www.domain.example/sitemap.xml`
If you use `domain.example` you would then submit `domain.example/sitemap.xml`

HTTPS has nothing to do with the use of `www`. (`www` is 'basically' a subdomain that points to `domain.example`)

If your site is using SSL, then you would submit it as `https://www.domain.example/sitemap.xml` or `https://domain.example/sitemap.xml`
(Or select HTTPS in the sitemap form if available.)